# echo not printing to file

Tags: linux, bash

i have a large list of telephone numbers I need to delete from a database, Im adding the telephone numbers to a single file on newlines and using the following script to generate the SQL insert command for me to manually paste.

```
file="Input.txt"
while IFS= read line
do
echo "delete from usr_preferences where uuid like '$line';"; >> output.txt
done <"$file"
```

Input file data -

```
1111111111
2222222222
3333333333
4444444444
```

It's working as expected other than it prints in the terminal rather than printing to file output.txt

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: `"; >>` - you need remove semicolon :)

Comment: just as the `;` terminates the SQL/delete statement, the `;` terminates a bash command (in this case the `echo`); leaving you with a new (bash) command of `>> output.txt` (which appends <nothing> to the file `output.txt`); what you want is `echo "delete ...'$line';" >> output.txt`

Comment: Aside: `while ...; do echo "..."; done <"$file" >>output.txt` could be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Do not construct SQL queries using string interpolation in *any* language. Use a language with a proper SQL library and let *it* construct properly parameterized queries.

Comment: be aware that expanding a variable inside any code without escaping it properly is a security hole

Comment: Also, sanitizing the input inside the loop wouldn't hurt: `[[ $line =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Invalid phone number: '$line'" >&2; exit; }`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  Andrey B. Panfilov and markp-fuso

Removing ; before the output command worked.